# Why does Assigned To: for an Activity to any admin, and only one other user not work since 4.6.7?

Tags: activities, permissions, acl, upgrade

We're on 4.6.9 and Drupal 7.

Ever since the changes to, then the rollback of, Access Control Levels (ACLs) /user permissions in 4.6.6/4.6.7/4.6.8 (see [here](https://civicrm.org/blogs/colemanw/civicrm-468-released-with-important-acl-bugfix)), I can Assign To: an Activity to all users *except* our two Admin users, and one other user, who has the same permissions as other users who can have an Assign To: for an activity.

I'll check these three user records (one of which is mine) for any corruption or other weirdness.

Has anyone else experienced this?

I'm not sure how I could duplicate on demo/sandbox without doing the same version updates/rollbacks we did from 4.6.6 to 4.6.8.

Answer (score 1):

In the any thoughts category: If you can't find it in 4.6.8 demo and you mention a rollback. A common problem with rollbacks is that when a table is created during an upgrade and you use a db dump to roll back to previous version, the created table stays in the database. If you then redo the upgrade, it does not expect that table to be there. So it could leave you with a system that is in disbalance.

So, my question is, when you did the rollback, did you remove and recreate the DB or did you just apply the db dump (with the risk of leaving a created table behind)?

If you did the latter: Do you still have your 4.6.6 DB? If so, could you immediately upgrade it to 4.6.8 and see if the problem still exists? If it doesn't, you could compare the table structures of your current live DB and this upgraded DB.

Comment: Thanks @Catorghans, will attempt to do the steps above - other folks were doing the rollback then updates for me.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I found that removing the API key in the Contact table for the other Admin user and I then allowed both of our names to appear in search as Assigned To: for Activities, but that "fix" doesn't work for another user, who had no API key. Thinking its something else particular to that user's ACL settings but they are not unique to that record. Any thoughts appreciated, thanks